# Do ancient Devanagari / Sanskrit manuscripts avoid ligatures?

Tags: sanskrit, manuscripts

I am looking at (for example) [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Aitareya_Upanishad%2C_Sanskrit%2C_Rigveda%2C_Devanagari_script%2C_1865_CE_manuscript.jpg):

[image]

In it, each individual character is isolated, as opposed to the "bar" that runs across modern Devanagari text. This got me wondering, are they not using ligatures in examples like this? Are they somehow just using very basic symbols? What are they doing?

Comment: Some special type of printer and/or font style may be one reason...bdw Gujrati doesn't hv that bar...

Comment: This is a language question. Suited for language sites.

Comment: maybe its the way they used to write, and it's definitely much clear to read then-current versions, maybe the reason that they used to use quills, instead of modern-day ballpoint pens, quills are easier to smudge so its better to keep characters separate.

Comment: The comments here are speculation. Please join the Sanskrit.SE (which you can find in Area 51). It is a burgeoning site and needs more questions like this

Comment: Sorry, here is the link: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language